# PCA generated initial matrix in gaussian and ellipse?

Tags: matlab, matrix, pca

I have to do PCA in Matlab for object recognition.

For now, I generate matrix randomly

```
 [a,InputMatrix] = sort(rand(100,20)); %Rows=100 Columns=20
 Average=mean(InputMatrix);
 CovarianceMatrix= cov(InputMatrix);
 %% Compute the Eigen Value and Eigen the Vector
 [EigVector,EigValue] = eigs(Matlab_Covariance);
 NewMatrix=(EigVector)*(EigValue)*(EigVector)';

 e1=EigVector(:,1); % Get the all the row at the first column
 e2=EigVector(:,2); % Get the all the row at the second column


 %% Plotting The Matrix with Eigen Value and Eigen Vector

 %creating all combinations of x and y coordinates
 [x,y]=meshgrid(1:size(InputMatrix,2),1:size(InputMatrix,1)); % 2= Columns 1= Rows
 x=x(:);
 y=y(:);

%plotting values of A such that X-Y axis represent the column and row coordinates of A
%respectively. Z-axis represents the value at that coordinate.
scatter3(x,y,InputMatrix(:),30,'rx');

%plotting the mean at the center of the coordinate system
hold on;

scatter3(mean([1:size(InputMatrix,2)]),mean([1:size(InputMatrix,1)]),
mean2(InputMatrix),60,'go','filled');
plot(e1,'k--');
plot(e2,'k--');
```

But if I perform PCA in that Random Matrix (InputMatrix), the shape of eigen vector e1 and e2 that I get for the PCA result will be wrong (when I plot them with InputMatrix in the same figure).

[image: **PCA Output**]

Someone told me that for the input matrix / data, it should be fulfill the condition (to be distributed in Normal Gaussian) and in elipse shape (when I plot it).
I think, I have to do rotation, scalling and other things to do it..

But I dont understand..

Could smeone please help me to generated random matrix with Normal Gaussian and in ellipse shape??
Please.. help me T_T

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by multiplying hidden components matrix to noise vectors, i. e., using underlying ICA model. To get higher dimensionality just change `cnum`.

```
close all; clear all;

cnum = 2;
nnum = 500;
C = rand(cnum, cnum); % hidden components
N1 = sort(rand(cnum, nnum)); % sorted uniform noise
D1 =  C * N1; % data
N2 = rand(cnum, nnum); % uniform noise
D2 =  C * N2; % data
N3 = randn(cnum, nnum); % Gaussian noise
D3 =  C * N3; % data

[V1, R1] = eig(cov(D3'));
[V2, R2] = eig(cov(D3'));
[V3, R3] = eig(cov(D3'));

subplot(1, 3, 1);
axis equal
hold on
plot(D1(1,:), D1(2,:), '.');
line([C(1, 1) 0 C(1, 2)], [C(2, 1) 0 C(2, 2)], 'Color', [1 .0 .0])
line([V1(1, 1) 0 V1(1, 2)], [V1(2, 1) 0 V1(2, 2)], 'Color', [.0 .0 .0])
title('Sorted uniform')

subplot(1, 3, 2);
axis equal
hold on
plot(D2(1,:), D2(2,:), '.');
line([C(1, 1) 0 C(1, 2)], [C(2, 1) 0 C(2, 2)], 'Color', [1 .0 .0])
line([V2(1, 1) 0 V2(1, 2)], [V2(2, 1) 0 V2(2, 2)], 'Color', [.0 .0 .0])
title('Uniform')

subplot(1, 3, 3);
axis equal
hold on
plot(D3(1,:), D3(2,:), '.');
line([C(1, 1) 0 C(1, 2)], [C(2, 1) 0 C(2, 2)], 'Color', [1 .0 .0])
line([V3(1, 1) 0 V3(1, 2)], [V3(2, 1) 0 V3(2, 2)], 'Color', [.0 .0 .0])
title('Gaussian')

print('-dpng', 'pca.png')
```

[image: Result]

Red lines represent hidden components and black lines represent PCA components.

Comment: Please see my question update with the full code and the output image that I got!! How to apply ur code in My code?? I got error!!

Comment: I already used randn instead of rand. But it still gives the wrong result in plotting e1 & e2.. can u please have a look at my code and tell me in which part i did wrong things.. Please

Comment: Because when I remove that sort command from my code, I get this error "Error using randn
Too many output arguments."

Comment: Yeahh, I already replace my code with "InputMatrix= rand(100,20); %Rows=100 Columns=20", but the plotted e1 and e2 is same (still error)

Comment: 2 is number of dimension/PCA components and 500 is number of data points.

Comment: do u mean Eigen Vector 1st Column and 2nd Column? But My data will be a matrix,, Not 1D.. it will be m*n (many features and many data that represent that features)!!

Comment: `[V,D] = eig(A) returns matrix V, whose columns are eigenvectors of A` - this is what is written in `eig` help. My data is 2D as visualizing N-dimensional data is not a trivial task.